# Charge moving in a wire; or not

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, conductors

A current flowing through a wire creates a magnetic field.

A current flowing through a wire represents electrons moving *very* slowly in the wire.

A wire contains electrons.

If I have an isolated section of copper wire, does it produce a magnetic field when I move it?

If not, why not?

Comment: if it needs to be 'charged' - i.e. have more electrons than protons - how much 'charge' would you need to put in to get a usable magnetic field?  and would this work?

Comment: worldbuilding usually focuses on questions with fictional worlds

Comment: An isolated copper wire moved around does not produce a magnetic field (see @AlexP's excellent summary). You can't kinetically shake electrons loose like a salt shaker. (a) When such a wire is moved through an existing magnetic field, however, that field causes electrons to move in the wire (which is how alternators and generators work - apply magnetic field, get electricity). (b) When electrons are forced to move in the wire, a magnetic field is produced (which is how motors, electromagnets, and solenoids work - apply electricity, get magnetic field).

Comment: What is your definition of "usable?" How do you want to use this magnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

"If I have an isolated section of copper wire, does it produce a magnetic field when I move it? If not, why not?"

You move as many protons (in the atomic nuclei) as you do electrons, and with the same velocity. But protons and electrons have equal and opposite charges, so the movement produces equal and opposite magnetic fields. These cancel.

Comment: Corollary: if there are more protons, or more electrons (i.e. the wire has a static charge), then moving it *does* produce a magnetic field. Not much, but nonzero.